# In LangChain, how to restrict agent-generated code before execution in PythonREPLTool?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop, agent, langchain, py-langchain

I am building an agent that can write and execute code with the PythonREPLTool to provide answers to questions. But I found that the agent often writes Python code that has "input()" to request input from the user.

I do not want the agent to execute code with "input()". Is there a way to forbid the execution of code with "input()" or simply add a timeout to the code execution process if the agent-generated code waits for input for a long time?

(I have tried the max_execution_time when initializing the agent but that does not seem to work.)

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a workaround for this problem. You can make GPT produce less "input()" in its result by using **Frequency and presence penalties**. Further detail here:
https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/parameter-details

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).